# Should model class contain method for loading all objects of its type?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, architecture

This question is more architecture related, but I'm gonna talk "in" one concrete programming language - objective c - since this language uses also class methods, not only instance methods(I'm not sure how it is in other languages). Also, I'm using MVC design pattern.

So, lets have a model class *Article*. This class would have properties like *title, description, text* etc... just basic stuff. Now, I want to load many articles from HTTP API. Should I do that inside the Article class in class method for example `+(void)loadAllArticlesWithBlock:...` (of course, it would use some HTTP manager class for that, that's not the point here),, or should the model class contain only stuff related to single Article and loading all articles should be let to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this as two separate questions:

- Should `Article` class server as a [*factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for `Article` objects, and
- Should `Article` factory be placed in the model or in the controller of MVC

The answer to the first question is "probably not": you would be better off defining a protocol for an article factory, and programming to that protocol. An implementation that supplies articles through HTTP API would be plugged in at runtime for production use. This opens a possibility of supplying a different factory for testing - say, one that loads articles from files.

The answer to the second question is that the object that hosts the factory method should be attached to the model, while all the uses of that object would come from controllers.